# MemoryError during Fast Fourier Transform on an image using NumPy arrays under Windows

Tags: python, windows, numpy, fft

The code could compute Fourier transform from a `.tiff` image on my Ubuntu 11.04. On Windows XP it produces memory error. What to change? Thank you.

```
def fouriertransform(result):     #function for Fourier transform computation
    for filename in glob.iglob ('*.tif')
        imgfourier = scipy.misc.imread(filename) #read the image
        arrayfourier = numpy.array([imgfourier])#make an array 
        # Take the fourier transform of the image.
        F1 = fftpack.fft2(arrayfourier)
        # Now shift so that low spatial frequencies are in the center.
        F2 = fftpack.fftshift(F1)
        # the 2D power spectrum is:
        psd2D = np.abs(F2)**2
        L = psd2D
        np.set_printoptions(threshold=3)
        #np.set_printoptions(precision = 3, threshold = None, edgeitems = None, linewidth = 3, suppress = True, nanstr = None, infstr = None, formatter = None)
        for subarray in L:
            for array in subarray:
                for array in subarray:
                    for elem in array:
                        print '%3.10f\n' % elem
```

The error output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\HrenMudak\Мои документы\Моя музыка\fourier.py", line 27, in <module>
    F1 = fftpack.fft2(arrayfourier)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\basic.py", line 571, in fft2
    return fftn(x,shape,axes,overwrite_x)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\basic.py", line 521, in fftn
    return _raw_fftn_dispatch(x, shape, axes, overwrite_x, 1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\basic.py", line 535, in _raw_fftn_dispatch
    return _raw_fftnd(tmp,shape,axes,direction,overwrite_x,work_function)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\basic.py", line 463, in _raw_fftnd
    x, copy_made = _fix_shape(x, s[i], waxes[i])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\basic.py", line 134, in _fix_shape
    z = zeros(s,x.dtype.char)
MemoryError
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to run your code, except that I replaced the `mahotas.imread` with the [`scipy.misc.imread`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) function, because I don't have that library, and I could not reproduce your error.

Some further remarks:

- can you try to use the `scipy.misc.imread` function instead of the `mahotas` function? I suppose the issue could be there
- what is the actual exception that is thrown? (+other output?)
- what are the dimensions of your image? Gray-scale / RGB? Printing all values for a large image could indeed take up quite some memory, so it might be better to visualize the results with e.g. matplotlibs `imshow` function.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried scipy function for reading the image, but result is the same, see the log error output

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image? i.e. try `print imgfourier.shape`

also, you could try to use the `flatten=True` option in imread: `imgfourier = imread(filename, flatten=True) #read the image`

Comment: thank you, image is a 90 MB .tiff (merged from 10 of them using IrphanView)

Comment: I set flatten = true for scipy.misc.imread function, same memory error occurs, thanks

Comment: 90 MB tiff image seems rather large; could be that the `imread` function is not suited for handling such large images. What do you mean by that it's merged from 10 other images? Are you by any chance trying to read a 3d (medical) image volume? Could you also test your code on another tif image?

Comment: image is stitched using IrphanView, I`ll try to process smaller images, I have tried to read the image using openCV and Mahotas read image functions,   thank you